# Removing keys from a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
[{'key':'key1', 'version':'1'}, {'key':'key2', 'version':'2'}, {'key':'key3', 'version':'3'}]
```

I want to remove all other keys from the dictionaries in the list and only to have 'key' and its value so the list would look like this:

```
[{'key': 'key1'}, {'key': 'key2'}, {'key': 'key3'}]
```

How can I extract it?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy solution. This uses the `.pop()` method to remove the key that you do not want. -

```
lst = [{'key':'key1','version':'1'},{'key':'key2','version':'2'},{'key':'key3','version':'3'}]

for dicts in lst:
    dicts.pop('version')

print(lst)
```

**Result**:

```
[{'key': 'key1'}, {'key': 'key2'}, {'key': 'key3'}]
```

This removes all `version` keys. Or you could use this method to remove everything except **desired key**:

```
new_l = []
for d in lst:
    for key in d:
        if key == 'key':
            new_l.append({key: d[key]})
print(new_l)
```

Or even simpler, you can use a **list and dictionary comprehension** to solve this. I recommend you to do this because it is more **readable** and **efficient.**:

```
new_l = [{key: d[key] for key in d if key == 'key'} for d in lst]
print(new_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l1 = [{'key':'key1','version':'1'},{'key':'key2','version':'2'},{'key':'key3','version':'3'}]

li2 = [{'key': j[x]} for j in l1 for x in j if x=='key']
print(li2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lst = [{'key':'key1','version':'1'},{'key':'key2','version':'2'},{'key':'key3','version':'3'}]

[item.pop('version') for item in lst]
```

Or, removing all possible keys that does not match 'key':

```py
lst = [{'key':'key1','version':'1'},{'key':'key2','version':'2'},{'key':'key3','version':'3'}]
for item in lst:
    for key in list(item.keys()):
        item.pop(key) if key!='key' else None
```

Comment: This will actually change the original dicts which might not be wanted

Comment: Also, don't use a list comprehension just for the side effects of the expression. Use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Also don't try to force code to one line. `item.pop(key) if key!='key' else None` doesn't make much sense. Why do you need that expression to return `None`. Why not use a normal `if key != 'key': item.pop(key)`. But also, you don't need the second loop at all... You can just do `if 'key' in item: item.pop('key')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
in just one line!

```py
yourList = [{'key':'key1','version':'1'},{'key':'key2','version':'2'},{'key':'key3','version':'3'}]
resultList = [{'key':dic['key']} for dic in yourList if 'key' in dic]
print(resultList)
```

Comment: OK I change my algorithm, that will not cause side-effects.

Comment: That's a lot better and to be honest, the best solution now. It doesn't needlessly iterate over all the keys when we know what key we need. I hope the downvoter reverts. +1 from me :)